# Beautifulsoup not extracting a <a> tag from a dynamic website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a website https://dip.bundestag.de/aktivit%C3%A4t/Dr--Holger-Becker-MdB-SPD/1628877 and I want to extract the HTML connected to "BT-Plenarprotokoll 20/86, S. 10313C". The HTML chunk is:

```
<a title="PDF Bundestags-Plenarprotokoll öffnen" aria-label="BT-Plenarprotokoll" href="https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf#P.10313" target="_self" class="hsbfb4-0 sc-1xaeas4-1 hTYfHF FZiNn"><svg viewBox="0 0 10 12" class="sc-1c5ggr5-17 cYBAUx"><g stroke="currentColor" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M6.14.5H.5v11h9V3.86z"></path><path d="M5.56 2.01v2.51H9.5"></path></g></svg><span class="sc-1xaeas4-3 iZuhXx">BT-Plenarprotokoll 20/86, S. 10313C</span></a>
```

For any reason, BeautifulSoup does not recognize any  tags on this webpage. I tried different codes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

   
url = "https://dip.bundestag.de/aktivit%C3%A4t/Dr--Holger-Becker-MdB-SPD/1628877"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the anchor tag with title and aria-label attributes and extract the href attribute
a_tag = soup.findAll('a', {'title': 'PDF Bundestags-Plenarprotokoll öffnen', 'aria-label': 'BT-Plenarprotokoll'})
```

and

```
url = "https://dip.bundestag.de/aktivit%C3%A4t/Dr--Holger-Becker-MdB-SPD/1628877"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the anchor tag with title and aria-label attributes and extract the href attribute
a_tag = soup.findAll('a')
```

In both cases, a_tag is an empty object, and I don't understand, since this webpage has more than one link.

Comment: Have you tried `View Source` on the website? Do you see the tags?

Comment: Yes, I got these tags from the source

Comment: I don't see any `<a>` tags in the source. I only see them in the Elements tab of DevTools. They're being loaded dynamically using AJAX.

Comment: Oh! Which library should I use to ge the content?

Comment: Read the lined question.

Comment: @Barmar you can get the data with `requests`. I voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use their API to get the data:

Note: The API Key is valid thru May and can be found [here](https://dip.bundestag.de/%C3%BCber-dip/hilfe/api).

For example:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Authorization': 'ApiKey GmEPb1B.bfqJLIhcGAsH9fTJevTglhFpCoZyAAAdhp',
}

url = "https://search.dip.bundestag.de/api/v1/aktivitaet?f.id=1628877"
documents = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()["documents"]
print(documents[0]["fundstelle"]["pdf_url"])
```

Output:

https://dserver.bundestag.de/btp/20/20086.pdf#P.10313

Comment: You got the id number from the url that I gave?

Comment: it works! I just want to know how did you get to this answer

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: In the Dev Tools, you can see there's a request made to an API endpoint. However, copy pasting it doesn't really cut it so I had to read the Swagger documentation for the DIP API and that's how I got it working.